# Retrieve revision number in VS with qmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mercurial, qmake

My current workflow:

1. *`hg update`* (or whatever one uses to check out a revision)
2. `MyProject.pro` → *`qmake`* → `MyProject.vcproj`
3. Open Visual Studio, edit files
4. Build project

During the build step, how can I update my `config.h` header file with information from version control system (e.g. *`hg id`*)?

`MyProject.vcproj` is generated by *`qmake`*, so I shouldn't edit it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute external commands from inside qmake. The easiest way to make the information available in your sources would be to use a define:

```
HGID = $$system(hg id)
DEFINES += HGID=\\\"$$HGID\\\"
```

I'm not sure if you can edit an external file from qmake. You could use an external tool, but on Windows you normally don't have things like `sed`, so it might be a little more problematic.

Comment: This command will be executed during qmake run. I want to execute it just before compiling source code. It seems there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish that using a custom build target and the `PRE_TARGETDEPS` keyword. Assuming `config.h.in` has the folowing format:

```
#define HGID $HGID
```

You can define a custom build target that will process `hgid.h.in` and output to `hgid.h` prior to building your main target as follows:

```
hgid.target = hgid
hgid.commands = sed s/\\\$$HGID/`hg id`/ hgid.h.in > hgid.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += hgid
PRE_TARGETDEPS += hgid
```

Comment: I'm unable to make it work after conversion to Visual Studio project (with qmake). It seems to disappear. If the very same command is added to `QMAKE_POST_LINK` then it properly shows up in post build step. (Yet for this use case it is far to late.)

Answer (score 1):

One opton is to enable the [Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension).  Put something like this in your hgrc (or Mercurial.ini if that's your thing):

```
[extensions]
hgext.keyword=

[keyword]
config.h =

[keywordmaps]
HGREV = {node}
```

Then in config.h put:

```
#define HGREV "$HGREV$"
```

You might need to parse the hex value out of the "$HGREV: deadbeefdeadbeef $" that you'll get, but that's easily done by whatever code is accessing the HGREV define.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lukáš Lalinský and goodrone's comment, I'd like to mention that qmake can link directly to the script, not only to it's output. So one can say

```
DEFINES += REPO_ID=\\\"`./setlocalversion.sh`\\\"
```

and the script will be freshly executed for every single target.

Comment: This does not work if the shell command contains spaces as qmake inserts `-D` into the command. You have to surround this with `'`:

    `'\\\"\`./setlocalversion.sh --some --parameters\`\\\"'`

(What an escape hell: SO markup, qmake, make, shell ...)

Comment: And as another complication: If the output of your command contains spaces as well you need another layer of double quotes. But then you cannot execute code with backticks anymore and you must use `$(shell)`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24010395/211520 for details.