# Add a define to qmake WITH a value?

Tags: qt, qmake

How do I add a define with qmake WITH a value:

For example, this does not work (as I expected) in my .pro file:

```
DEFINES += WINVER 0x0500
```

nor

```
DEFINES += "WINVER 0x0500"
```

How do I define WINVER as 0x0500 before anything starts compiling so it's definition is not affected in any way by compilation or include order?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`DEFINES += "WINVER=0x0500"` works for me.

This way, `-DWINVER=0x0500` is added to the command line of the compiler, which is the syntax GCC/mingw expects for command line preprocessor definitions (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) for the details).

Comment: +1 This works perfectly, thanks! It added `-DWINVER=0x0500` to the Makefile just as you said. PS - I didn't need the quotes since there's no spaces. ;)

Comment: For posterity's sake, if you want to define a string value in the qmake file, it seems that you must use a rather strange combination of slashes and quotes: DEFINES += MY_DEF='\\"string\\"'

Answer (score 56):

```
DEFINES += MY_DEF=\\\"String\\\"
```

This format is to be used when one intends to have the macro replaced by string element

Answer (score 31):

As an addendum, if you want to execute shell code instead of just setting a constant (e.g. for getting a version number or a date):

Either use `$$system()`. This is **run when qmake is executed:**

```
DEFINES += GIT_VERSION=$$system(git describe --always)
```

Or use `$()` if the code should be **run on every build** (i.e. when the makefile is executed).
For `DEFINES` you need to escape the command if it contains spaces, otherwise qmake inserts unwanted `-D`'s:

```
DEFINES += GIT_VERSION='$(shell git describe --always)'
```

This will then be copied literally into the makefile.

If the command's output contains spaces, you need another layer of escapement (this time for make):

```
DEFINES += BUILD_DATE='"$(shell date)"'
```

If you need quotes around your value to get a string, it gets a bit ugly:

```
DEFINES += BUILD_DATE='"\\\"$(shell date)\\\""'
```

I would recommend to use the preprocessors stringify operation in this case:

```
#define _STR(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)  _STR(x)

printf("this was built on " STRINGIFY(BUILD_DATE) "\n");
```

Comment: +1 for the GIT_VERSION example and notes about escaping quotes. OT but I've found the following most useful `GIT_VERSION=\\\"$$system(git describe --always --abbrev=0)\\\"` to get the latest tag version, or failing that the current commit

Comment: not that the «every build» option won't work in Windows (as the build is performed via nmake, not a real make)

Comment: STRINGIFY made my life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 12):

**#define STRING "Value with spaces" fro Qt *.PRO file :**

In order to add a *#define STRING "Value with spaces"* from QT Project file, we had to write :

```
DEFINES += "VERSION_LOG=\"\\\"Version 2.5.1\\\"\""
DEFINES += "VERSION_QT=\"\\\"Qt 5.10\\\"\""
```

which gives into the Makefile.Release file :

```
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DVERSION_LOG="\"Version 2.5.1\"" -DVERSION_QT="\"Qt 5.10\"" -DQT_NO_DEBUG [...]
```

In summary, on that line : `DEFINES += "VERSION_LOG=\"\\\"Version 2.5.1\\\"\""`

The first and last `"` tells QMake to read the entire sentence as a string

The first and last `\"` writes the first and last `"` into `-DVERSION_LOG="\"Version 2.5.1\""`

The first and last `\\\"` writes a `\` then a `"` into `-DVERSION_LOG="\"Version 2.5.1\""`

Answer (score 4):

Greg's answer works fine in a .pro file. However, when calling qmake from the command line, I had to leave away the spaces, i.e. use sth. like the following, to make a define work :

```
qmake DEFINES+="WINVER 0x0500"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a string literal for use in Objective-C then you need to remember the @ before the escaped quotes

```
DEFINES += MY_DEF='@\\"string-literal\\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run qmake in bash script and want to use VERSION (semver) from bash script as QString variable, you can do:

In bash:

```
qmake Project.pro DEFINES+=VERSION=\"1.0.0\"
```

In .cpp:

```
#define _STR(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)  _STR(x)

QString version = QString(STRINGIFY(VERSION))
```