# Conditionally link to shared library on a define in qmake

Tags: c++, c, qt, qmake

I have a code which is branched by `#define` directive, for example:

```
#ifdef USE_LIB_CRYPTO
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#else
#include <cryptopp/pwdbased.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#endif
```

Depending on is defined `USE_LIB_CRYPTO` or not I should add

```
LIBS += -lcrypto
```

or

```
LIBS += -lcryptopp
```

How can I do that? For example, this should be controlled by:

> qmake ./ DEFINES+="USE_LIB_CRYPTO"

So I need to somehow check is `define` passed to qmake and link to the library I need.

Comment: Always add the lib dependency. If it is not necessary, linker make the job for you.

Comment: @LPs if I link to a library which does not exist on the build machine I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdfjiijasdf` so I think this should be controlled.

Comment: Well, obviously it is required to exists on you SDK.

Comment: BTW you can use `CONFIG` like shown into [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14458172/3436922)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value) test function of the qmake.

```
contains ( DEFINES, USE_LIB_CRYPTO ){
    LIBS += -lcrypto
} else {
    LIBS += -lcryptopp
}
```