# Is the QT DEFINES doing the same thing as #define in C++?

Tags: c++, qt

What does the `DEFINES += includthisvariable` do in QT for a `.pro` file?

If it works like the `#define` in C++, where is `includethisvariable` defined so that the preprocessor can replace `includethisvariable` with the value I set?

I understand what `#define` does in c++ because you set the value beside what you define. However here it seems like you just list a name...The QT docs didn't help explain this for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a define to qmake WITH a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348711/add-a-define-to-qmake-with-a-value)

Comment: Please refer to the possible duplicate: the answers here are plainly wrong about how to pass string literals to the -D option.

Answer (score 22):

The items in the Qt Project file's `DEFINES` variable end up on the compiler's command line with the `-D` option (or whatever is appropriate for the compiler being used).  To give your macro definition a value instead of merely defining it, use the following:

```
DEFINES += FOOBAR=foobar_value
```

That will show up on the compiler's command line as `-DFOOBAR=foobar_value`

If you need spaces you need to quote the value - and escape the quotes that'll be passed on the compiler command line:

```
DEFINES += FOOBAR="\"foobar value\""
```

This one shows up as: `-DFOOBAR="foobar value"`

Comment: /D on Windows, -D on Linux, OSX, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it works in the same way. `DEFINES += includethisvariable` includes the pre-processor symbol `includethisvariable` in the sources being compiled.

This means any #ifdef statements like

```
#ifdef includethisvariable
...
...
#endif
```

are included in the source being compiled.

Macros with values can also be defined

```
`DEFINES += "MAXBUFFERSIZE=4096"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to define a macro of a string literal in your qmake file, equivalent to `#define VAR "Some string"`

It's gonna look like this:

```
DEFINES += CODE_WORKING_DIR=\\\"$$PWD\\\"
```

So that it would produce that as an argument to g++ (or whatever you're using to compile):

```
g++ -c -DCODE_WORKING_DIR=\"/path/to/my/code\"
```

It is ugly. If someone knows a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-project-generic.html):

> The defines are specified in the .config file. The .config file is a
>   regular C++ file, prepended to all your source files when they are
>   parsed. Only use the .config file to add lines as in the example
>   below:

```
#define NAME value
```

Comment: Can't edit (edit queue is full, so I'll post a working link as a comment): http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-generic.html#specifying-defines