# Determine active qmake configuration in C++ files

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, preprocessor

I have an Qt/C++ application which uses several configuration. So in Build settings I've added my 2 custom configurations in addition to standard `Release` end `Debug`. 
[image]

Now in QtCreator I can select desired configuration to build the application using appropriate configuration.

But I don't know how to read this configuration in a C++ file. I want something like the following:

```
#if defined CONFIG1
...
#elif defined CONFIG2
...
#else
...
#endif
```

How to do that?

Comment: `#ifdef`? (5 more to go)

Comment: The "configuration" you want to "read", it's not a C++ source or header file you build with the project? It's an actual text-file you want to read in your program at run-time? By "configuration" do you mean a macro you use in a source or header file? Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "read this configuration".

Comment: I just want to determine active configuration. in C++ files of course.

Comment: Then what is wrong with what you show us? Have you tried it? With your current attempt, what works and what doesn't work? Do you get build errors? Run-time errors? Please be as detailed and specific as possible.

Comment: CONFIG1, CONFIG2 is for example. I don't know where to set it. `#if Configuration_name` doesn't work.

Comment: are you porting from QtCreator to `qmake`? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350169/7926064) helps.

Comment: Each "configuration" should allow you to add macros specific for it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to you guys I've found the solution. There is `Additional arguments` in the `Build step` tab for custom variables. I've added here:

> "DEFINES += CONFIG1"

for specified configuration. Quotes are necessary. It will be converted to `-DCONFIG1` command line argument for g++ and so in C++ code it could be used as following:

```
#ifdef CONFIG1
    // code here
#endif
```